# pretty url for jekyll page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, jekyll, naming

I'm building a small Jekyll site with a number of pages. I would really like to get the page (*not* post) links to a pretty state like:

`foo.com/bar/`

But I can't figure out how to get past:

`foo.com/_site/bar/index.html`

I can link to:

`foo.com/bar.html`

Of course, but that only returns my YAML front material. As you can tell, I haven't quite grokked the Jekyll naming system. Is there an easy way to do this within Jekyll, or will I have to rewrite the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: foo.com/_site/bar/index.html = foo.com/_site/bar/

Comment: Move (with FTP) the contents of your _site folder to static hosting and it works. Do not serve Jekyll. Serve the content of the _site folder.

Comment: Okay, that was the answer I was hoping for. Thanks so much!

Comment: Nice! I am glad it works now!

Answer (score 4):

You can just type `permalink: pretty` in your _config.yml.

Source: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/#builtinpermalinkstyles

Comment: They must have made a mistake in the documentation of Jekyll... ;-)

Comment: I'm telling you! (Seriously, I love Jekyll, but there's not much documentation for what to do when it doesn't work as intended.)

Comment: This settings makes sure your URL's do not end in 'bar.html' but in 'bar/index.html'.

Answer (score 1):

Use this syntax at the top of your jekyll md/html page file:

```
---
title: bar
permalink: /bar/
---
```

Use this in addition to anything already in the header section of your jekyll page.